# Angular Live compiling

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am working on a large project developed by the angular framework, this project contains hundreds of components, in the development mode each change in the code the server recompiles all the chunks which takes almost 2 minutes to finish the build. Is there a way to make the refresh faster? We cannot specify the component to recompile (just the component that has undergone a modification).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using `ng build` or `ng serve` in your development mode?

Comment: Hello John, i use ng serve to start the project.

Comment: my guess is that you have multiple children modules, like children module on a children module and so on, am i right?

Comment: Yes i'm using lazy loading so i have a sub module on each component. Is it this the cause of slowness of compiling?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Yes i think thats the cause of the slowness of your build, you need to refactor it, find sub-modules that you think can be just added directly to the parent without wrapping it in a module

Comment: John thanks a lot for your answer, David I use angular 7